# ArtifactTransferException eclipse error when guice added

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guice, m2eclipse

I'm trying to add guice to my Google App Engine project.  I'm using Maven and Eclipse.  In Eclipse, I modified my pom.xml by adding the following to the `<dependencies>` element as per http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice/3.0:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, Eclipse has raised four errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out pom.xml /audiencemarketing-backend  line 123    Maven Dependency Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0    pom.xml /audiencemarketing-backend  line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/mosofsky/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar'   audiencemarketing-backend       Build path  Build Path Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    audiencemarketing-backend       Unknown Java Problem
```

I have tried right-clicking my project and choosing Maven => Update Project.  But I still get the same 4 errors.  I also tried Project => Clean and same thing.

How do I correctly add Guice given my setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by going to my command line and issuing the command `mvn clean install`.  Maven had no trouble obtaining the guice library from the Maven Central Repository.  Then I went back into Eclipse and right-clicked my project and choose Maven => Update Project.

This resolved all the errors I was seeing and made Eclipse happy.